# Bitwise flag in ORMLite

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, lambda, ormlite

I have a bitwise flag column in my db table and I wanna select rows that does not have a certain flag. For example I want to retrieve list of customers that are not deactivated.

I write this in ORMLite

```
var q = db.Select<Customer>().where(c => (c.Flags & CustomerFlag.Deactive) != CustomerFlag.Deactive);
```

But when I watch the query that ORMLite generates in debug, '&' turns to 'AND'.
So I can't get what I want.

I also used HasFlag. But It seems it's not supported by ORMLite.

Does anybody have a solution?

p.s: DB is SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer **my own** question. But it seems that I finally found an answer. I write it down to help if anyone faced the same issue.

Actually I replace the 'bitwise' part of lambda with a raw sql codition:

```
var q = db.Select<Customer>().Where($"(Flags & {(int)CustomerFlag.Deactive} != {(int)CustomerFlag.Deactive}");
```

So the generated query is like:

```
select * from customer where (flag & 8) <> 8
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not implemented in the OrmLite. The fact that single AND `&` even works is a coincidence.

Look at the source [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Expressions/SqlExpression.cs), scroll down to this method:

```
protected virtual string BindOperant(ExpressionType e)
```

The `switch` statement lists binary operators that get converted to SQL operators. Note that `ExpressionType.And` is missing from the list; only `ExpressionType.AndAlso` is present.

Therefore, `ExpressionType.And` falls to the `default` case:

```
default:
    return e.ToString();
```

This is the same as returning `AND`, which SQL interprets as logical `AND`.

There is no work-around for this issue.

Since the source of the project is freely available, you can submit a fix to this problem. The solution may be as simple as adding these four lines to the `switch` statement in `SqlExpression.cs` file:

```
case ExpressionType.And:
    return "&";
case ExpressionType.Or:
    return "|";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Yes you right, unfortunately It's not implemented in ORMLite. But I found an alternative solution. it's seems that we can write a raw SQL condition too. So as I answered my own question, I handled this Bit-wise part with raw SQL.

Comment: @Azade I don't have a way to verify this, but there's a decent chance that adding two lines to `SqlExpression.cs` file may solve the problem. Please take a look.